How can I increase the amount of available memory available Solr in a Docker container?
I downloaded Solr from dockerhub and I am trying to increase the amount of available memory available to Solr. It seems that the JVM args are set to "-Xms512m -Xmx512" which means that there are only 512 mb available to Solr. How can I increase that limit?

Set the SOLR_HEAP environment variable when you launch the container.
For example:
docker run -it --rm -e SOLR_HEAP=1024m solr:latest

The running process will then have -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m.
You could also create a derived image with the required settings.
FROM solr:latest

ENV SOLR_HEAP=1024m


How can I change the environment variable on an existing docker container?

Once the process is running in an existing container changing the environment variable is not going to have any effect. I am not aware of a way to change the memory management settings on a running Java process. I'd suggest that you terminate the existing container and start a new one with the environment settings in place.
